# How can I sum in group by type?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'd like to create a Jasper template, something which gives the following output:

```
2016-01-01
     Category         Descritpiton               Income
     --------         ------------               ------
            A         ...                        1230
            B         ...                        1000
            A         ...                         100
            C         ...                        2500
            B         ...                          10
            A         ...                          10
            A         ...                           5
    +--------------------------------------------------+
    Sum
            A                                    1355
            B                                    1010
            C                                     100

2016-01-02
     Category         Descritpiton               Income
     --------         ------------               ------
            A         ...                         500
            B         ...                         100
            B         ...                         100
            E         ...                        2500
            B         ...                          10
            A         ...                          10
            A         ...                           5
    +--------------------------------------------------+
    Sum
            A                                     515
            B                                     210
            E                                    2500

(more days...)
```

I have an SQL datasource, with a Table with the necessary columns. I could create a report, where the incomes grouped by the day (I achieved this with one group, and an order-by in the SQL select statement). Something like this:

```
2016-01-01
     Category         Descritpiton               Income
     --------         ------------               ------
            A         ...                        1230
            B         ...                        1000
            A         ...                         100
            C         ...                        2500
            B         ...                          10
            A         ...                          10
            A         ...                           5

2016-01-02
     Category         Descritpiton               Income
     --------         ------------               ------
            A         ...                         500
            B         ...                         100
            B         ...                         100
            E         ...                        2500
            B         ...                          10
            A         ...                          10
            A         ...                           5

(more days...)
```

But I cannot create the sums at the end of each day. Is there a way, to achieve the given sum-by-category part of the report?

Comment: Executing another sql statement to have the sum values is an accepted solution?

Comment: No, I'd like to avoid the second sql creation.

Comment: I will pass you an answer but avoiding second sql will force you to develop a java class (or are the category fixed there are always A,B,C?)

Comment: The categories not fix. I have no problem with the Java class, thanks!

Comment: I posted you an answer with the different solutions, the other maybe helpful to other users... You key problem is that if you are not doing the "normal" design, you will need a new datasource for your sum table. If you do not like to re-query (that would be fairly simple), you need to store the values as report is running and the request the datasource from your java class

Comment: You can see that in JRDefaultScriptlet you will have some useful metods to be able to construct your new datasource, beforeGroupInit(java.lang.String groupName), afterDetailEval(), try it out!, if you have problem, consider asking a new question with the java code you tried, your output and your expected out. I will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Honestly, the report is generated from a Java app, where the select query (and only a single select) is stored. Is there a way, to generate the second select from the report, if I provide the column of the second group by? If no, can you post an example of the re-query solution, please? It may be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100742/discussion-between-petter-friberg-and-nagy-vilmos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When grouping in jasper report, you will get access to two new bands, `groupHeader` and `groupFooter`.

Your need to add the sum table in the `groupFooter`.

**Normal design** (re-design report to avoid the need for a new datasource, grouping also on category)

```
2016-01-01
     Category         Description               Income
     --------         ------------               ------
            A         ...                        1230
            A         ...                         100 
     +--------------------------------------------------+
    Total sum category A                         1335

            B         ...                        1000

           ..........................................
    Total sum  all                               6000
```

If this is not an option you will need a new datasource for your sum table

**Solution 1** (re query):

Add a `subreport` or `jr:table` in the `groupFooter` and re-query your database with the date as parameter (group on category and sum value)

**Solution 2** (Create jasper report scriplet, [JRDefaultScriptlet](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDefaultScriptlet.html))

Create a java class extending the `JRDefaultScriptlet` class, that stores and sum your values as the report is filled. In solution 1 call scriptlet to get for example a [JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html) that can be used as datasource to fill your sum table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think the re-query will be the least painful solution for me.